# Assign Json string to a single key

Tags: json, python-3.x, python-2.7

Below is my python code that reads the data from a file and converts into JSON

```py
json_data = {}

data ={}

with open("json_content.txt","r") as fp:

    for line in fp.readlines():
     if line != '\n':
       line=line.strip()
       split_data = line.split(':',)
       json_data[split_data[0].strip()] = split_data[1].split('\n')[0].strip()
       data['description']=json_data
      elif line == '\n':
       print(data)
```

my python code gives me the output as below

```
{'description': {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb'}}
{'description': {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '1.5T', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb'}}
{'description': {'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '3.5T', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb'}}
```

But i am looking for an output as below

```
{'description': 

    { 'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '2.5T', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb'}
    { 'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '1.5T', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb'}
    { 'mount_disk': '/data', 'actual_size': '3.5T', 'fsystem': '/dev/sdb'}
}
```

How can I get the expected output as above?

Answer (score 0):

You can't add multiple objects to a single key without using an array. You target JSON structure has to look like this:

```
{
  "description": [
    {"mount_disk": "/data", "actual_size": "2.5T", "fsystem": "/dev/sdb"},
    {"mount_disk": "/data", "actual_size": "2.5T", "fsystem": "/dev/sdb"},
    ...
  ]
}
```

So your `data` object in python should contain a list at with the key `description` to which you will add each object:

```py
json_data = {}
data = {"description": []}

with open("json_content.txt","r") as fp:
    for line in fp.readlines():
        if line != '\n':
            line=line.strip()
            split_data = line.split(':',)
            json_data[split_data[0].strip()] = split_data[1].split('\n')[0].strip()
            data['description'].append(json_data)
         elif line == '\n':
            print(data)
```

Comment: thanks for the support.
From your code the output seems to be recurring values for key description and gives me 3 sets of description output.